# Виснет обучение сетки на GPU. Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Установил Tensorflow 2.10. CUDA, cuDNN есть, сам тф видит видяху. Проблема в том, что обучение сетки виснет (судя по всему даже не начинается). Как это выглядит в dataspell:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался разобраться, в чем может быть проблема, похоже, что тф все-таки взаимодействует с видеокартой, на графике ГП: первый подскок - подгрузка датасета, второй подскок - инициализация модели, однако при запуске `.fit()` никакой реакции от ГП не наблюдается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Грешил на переполнение памяти, но никаких варнингов не было (на всякий случай прикреплю код погрузки данных, буду рад критике):

```
ds_train_ = image_dataset_from_directory(
    DATA_PATCH_TRAIN,
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='binary',
    image_size=[128, 128],
    interpolation='nearest',
    batch_size=64,
    shuffle=True,
)
ds_valid_ = image_dataset_from_directory(
    DATA_PATCH_TEST,
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='binary',
    image_size=[128, 128],
    interpolation='nearest',
    batch_size=64,
    shuffle=False,
)

# Data Pipeline
def convert_to_float(image, label):
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)
    return image, label

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
ds_train = (
    ds_train_
    .map(convert_to_float)
    .cache()
    .prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
)
ds_valid = (
    ds_valid_
    .map(convert_to_float)
    .cache()
    .prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
)
```

Честно говоря, не знаю, что еще может пригодиться для решения проблемы, если что, требуйте :) Зарание спасибо